# Selenuim click not activating events

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

I'm using selenuim with python and I'm trying to click an element. I'm using selenuim's wait function to wait for the button to be found and to become clickable. The button seems ok and i can see the click's animation on screen, yet nothing is happening.

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with chrome driver, selenuim or mabey it's just the Js that didn't connect to the button in time.

This is a short version of the failed code section:

```
webElement = WebDriverWait(self, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, value)),
EC.element_to_be_clickable(self)).click()
```

the wait is not failing and the element is clicked. For some reason the event of the button is not happening...

Comment: Can you share URL or how looks html section code, element and some close parents and childrens

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.